# What data type is the CreatedById

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am trying to query records (of a custom object) that were created by the current logged in user.

I am trying to use the Created By field to check this. However I can't figure out what the field really is or how to compare it. If I get the record thusly:

```
SELECT id, Name, CreatedById '+'FROM Reservation__c
```

And then display this in a VF page I get a first name last name format with a link. I know that is listed as a lookup field, but is there a way to get the id number?

But on the same page if I use this VF markup:

```
Hello ID {! $User.Id }
```

I get an 18 digit user ID.

How can I get a CreatedBy ID that I can compare to the current user ID in Apex code?

Comment: It's an ID, but it can also be understood as a String

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CreatedById is an `Id` field just as Id is, so you can compare the two very simply.

To query records created by the current logged in user:

```
[SELECT Id, Name, CreatedById FROM Reservation__c WHERE CreatedById = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

--or--

```
Database.query('SELECT Id, Name, CreatedById FROM Reservation__c WHERE CreatedById = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\'');
```

... with all `lookup` and `master-detail` fields, the field itself (when queried) is an `Id`.  Salesforce's UI recognizes that it's a reference and instead displays the corresponding record's `Name` field.

Standard fields toggle the `Id` demarcation at the end:

**Id   = CreatedById**

**Name = CreatedBy.Name**

Custom fields toggle the `__c` for `__r` at the end:

**Id   = ParentRecord__c**

**Name = ParentRecord__r.Name**